# What does the operator ?= mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml, frontend, hamlc

I have a hamlc (known as Haml + Inline CoffeeScript) which has a line like

```
- @variable1 ?= @object1.element[0]
```

I wonder if this means: if `@object1.element[0]` has a value then store it inside `@variable1`.

I cannot find any info about hamlc. Also, if what I understand is right, what if I want to add an `else` condition?

Comment: `- if variable1
    ="//do something if"
  else
    ="//do something else"`

breake into lines

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @7urkm3n

Comment: Also, this one should work: `@variable1 = @object? ? @object1.element[0] : 'EMPTRY @object'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?=` operator is known as the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) in CoffeeScript.

From the docs:

> It's a little difficult to check for the existence of a variable in JavaScript. if (variable) ... comes close, but fails for zero, the empty string, and false. CoffeeScript's existential operator ? returns true unless a variable is null or undefined, which makes it analogous to Ruby's nil?

That means that the way it works is, using your example:

```
 @variable1 ?= @object1.element[0]
```

If `@variable1` is `null` or `undefined`, assign `@object1.element[0]` to it.

> what if I want to add the condition for "else" ?

```
@variable1 = 
  if @variable1?
    @object1.element[0]
  else
    # your else clause here
```

Comment: Actually, you can also `... = @variable1 ? @object1.element[0]`